# Using a class to operate both as decorator and decorator factory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

Consider the following decorator function, which either returns a decorated function, or a parametrized decorat**or** function:

```py
from functools import wraps, partial, update_wrapper
from inspect import signature

def wrapit(func=None, *, verb='calling'):
    if func is None:  # return a decoratOR
        return partial(wrapit, verb=verb)
    else:  # return a decoratED
        @wraps(func)
        def _func(*args, **kwargs):
            print(f'{verb} {func.__name__} with {args} and {kwargs}')
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return _func
```

Demo:

```py
>>> f = lambda x, y=1: x + y
>>> ff = wrapit(verb='launching')(f)
>>> assert ff(10) == 11
launching <lambda> with (10,) and {}
>>> assert signature(ff) == signature(f)
>>>
>>> # but can also use it as a "decorator factory"
>>> @wrapit(verb='calling')
... def f(x, y=1):
...     return x + y
...
>>> assert ff(10) == 11
launching <lambda> with (10,) and {}
>>> assert signature(ff) == signature(f)
```

The class form could look something like this:

```py
class Wrapit:
    def __init__(self, func, verb='calling'):
        self.func, self.verb = func, verb
        update_wrapper(self, func)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f'{self.verb} {self.func.__name__} with {args} and {kwargs}')
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
```

But how do we get the class to be able to operate in the "decorator factory" mode that the functional form has (implemented by the `if func is None: return partial...`
How do we integrate that trick in a decorator class?

Comment: you could do the same trick in `__new__`

Comment: Not sure what you mean @juanpa.arrivillaga. `__new__` takes a class only, so how can I condition what I do based on `func is None`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was suggested in the comments, you can do this using the `__new__` method:

```
class Wrapit:
    def __new__(cls, func=None, *, verb='calling'):
        if func is None:
            return partial(cls,verb=verb)
        self = super().__new__(cls)
        self.func, self.verb = func, verb
        update_wrapper(self, func)
        return self

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f'{self.verb} {self.func.__name__} with {args} and {kwargs}')
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
```

The `__new__` method is called whenever you try to instantiate a class, and the return value of that method is used as the result of the attempted instantiation -- even if it's not an instance of the class!

Comment: Accepting your answer. Thanks. Note that I edited your answer a bit (replaced `object.__new__(cls)` with `super(Wrapit, cls).__new__(cls)` etc.). Revert if you disagree.

Comment: @thorwhalen I accepted that change, but rejected the change to split it into two methods, which I don't think is clearer (I chose "reject and edit", as I'm never sure whether to use it or "Improve edit" when I want to accept half an edit)

Answer (score 1):

I accepted @pppery's answer because... it was the answer. I wanted to extend the answer here by showing how one can get a bit more reuse by coding the logic in a parent class. This requires one to separate @pppery's logic into the `__new__` and `__init__` methods.

```py
from functools import update_wrapper, partial

class Decorator:
    def __new__(cls, func=None, **kwargs):
        if func is None:
            self = partial(cls, **kwargs)
        else:
            self = super().__new__(cls)
        return update_wrapper(self, func)

    def __init__(self, func=None, **kwargs):
        self.func = func
        for attr_name, attr_val in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, attr_name, attr_val)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
```

```py
class Wrapit(Decorator):
    def __new__(cls, func=None, *, verb='calling'):
        return super().__new__(cls, func, verb=verb)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f'{self.verb} {self.func.__name__} with {args} and {kwargs}')
        return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)

class AnotherOne(Decorator):
    def __new__(cls, func=None, *, postproc=lambda x: x):
        return super().__new__(cls, func, postproc=postproc)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.postproc(super().__call__(*args, **kwargs))
```

Demo:

```py
>>> f = lambda x, y=1: x + y
>>> 
>>> ff = Wrapit(f, verb='launching')
>>> assert ff(10) == 11
launching <lambda> with (10,) and {}
>>> assert signature(ff)  == signature(f) 
>>> 
>>> fff = AnotherOne(postproc=str)(f)  # doing it the decorator factory way
>>> assert fff(10) == str(11)
>>> assert signature(fff)  == signature(f)
```

Comment: Thanks, @pppery. I must say though, it's not my ideal version: The subclass `__new__` methods are only there to  provide the signature of the subclass decorator factory, but doesn't do any real work beyond that. I've been looking to simplify that aspect too. I'll post that in a separate question and direct you to it.

Comment: @pppery: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62399050/a-lean-interface-for-making-python-decorator-classes