# A lean interface for making python decorator classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datamodel

I've been looking to make an object-oriented setup to make decorator factories. A simple version can be found in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62380011/5758423). But I'm not totally satisfied with the simplicity of the interface.

THe kind of interface I envision would use special class `Decora` that I can use as such:

```py
class MultResult(Decora):
    mult: int = 1
    i_am_normal = Literal(True)  # will not be included in the __init__

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):  # code for the wrapped functoin
        return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs) * self.mult
```

That would result in the following behavior:

```py
>>> @MultResult(mult=2)
... def f(x, y=0):
...     return x + y
...
>>>
>>> signature(MultResult)  # The decorator has a proper signature
<Signature (func=None, *, mult: int = 1)>
>>> signature(f)  # The decorated has a proper signature
<Signature (x, y=0)>
>>> f(10)
20
>>>
>>> ff = MultResult(lambda x, y=0: x + y)  # default mult=1 works
>>> assert ff(10) == 10
>>>
>>> @MultResult  # can also use like this
... def fff(x, y=0):
...     return x + y
...
>>> assert fff(10) == 10
>>>
>>> MultResult(any_arg=False)  # should refuse that arg!
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TypeError: TypeError: __new__() got unexpected keyword arguments: {'any_arg'}
```

Comment: I'm not going to cast a close vote because I consider myself too involved, but this question, out of context, feels like a too broad (or "Needs more focus" after a bunch of pointless wording changes) "please do my work for me" question.

Comment: It's no where near "please do my work for me" -- I'm about to post a working answer myself, but wanted to expose to the experts out there because there may be a more elegant solution,

Comment: The problem is that there isn't really a question in the question.

Comment: @Blckknght There is a clear question, in my opinion, it's "write some code that has the behavior described" -- but I would recommend waiting for the foreshadowed self-answer before engaging in any further moderation activity on this question.

Comment: That's exactly right @pppery: It's exactly the setup I gave myself -- test driven style. I wrote the kind of code interface II wanted, and some tests, and finally the objects that made the tests pass. The question is "is there a 'better' way to do this than I've done". Not sure what is the accepted SO-community way of saying that.

Comment: What is `i_am_normal` supposed to do, why is its value `Literal(True)`, and what is `Literal`?

Comment: Now that this has an answer posted, I don't agree that it is not too broad. Nevertheless, it is kind of turning the standard Q&A model on its head, in that what you are actually asking is "please suggest improvements to this answer", not "please answer this question". If what you are asking is "how can I improve this code", I would recommend aggregating the question and answer into one complete, working, snippet (as opposed to scattered code blocks), and posting that as a question on [codereview.se]. This is kind of unclear/too broad as a Stack Overflow question right now.

Comment: If you're asking "is there another entirely independent way of doing this", then this isn't really suitable for Code Review, but it isn't really suitable for Stack Overflow either because it regresses back into the "please do my work for me" I mentioned earlier in the comments.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica: You're right, I forgot the (very simple) definition of `Literal`. Included it now. It's just a means to tell `__init_subclass__` if one wants to take the attribute value literally -- i.e. not be processed as an intended `__new__` argument.

Answer (score 0):

We can start with a base such as this:

```py
from functools import partial, update_wrapper

class Decorator:
    """A transparent decorator -- to be subclassed"""
    def __new__(cls, func=None, **kwargs):
        if func is None:
            return partial(cls, **kwargs)
        else:
            self = super().__new__(cls)
            self.func = func
            for attr_name, attr_val in kwargs.items():
                setattr(self, attr_name, attr_val)
            return update_wrapper(self, func)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
```

It allows one to define decorator factories by subclassing and defining a `__new__` method (that should call its parent).

Then, one can use `__init_subclass__` to extract the desired arguments of that `__new__` directly from attributes of the subclass, as such:

```py
from inspect import Signature, Parameter

PK, KO = Parameter.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD, Parameter.KEYWORD_ONLY

class Literal:
    """An object to indicate that the value should be considered literally"""
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

class Decora(Decorator):
    _injected_deco_params = ()

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        if '__new__' not in cls.__dict__:  # if __new__ hasn't been defined in the subclass...
            params = ([Parameter('self', PK), Parameter('func', PK, default=None)])
            cls_annots = getattr(cls, '__annotations__', {})
            injected_deco_params = set()
            for attr_name in (a for a in cls.__dict__ if not a.startswith('__')):
                attr_obj = cls.__dict__[attr_name]  # get the attribute
                if not isinstance(attr_obj, Literal):
                    setattr(cls, attr_name, attr_obj)  # what we would have done anyway...
                    # ... but also add a parameter to the list of params
                    params.append(Parameter(attr_name, KO, default=attr_obj,
                                            annotation=cls_annots.get(attr_name, Parameter.empty)))
                    injected_deco_params.add(attr_name)
                else:  # it is a Literal, so
                    setattr(cls, attr_name, attr_obj.val)  # just assign the literal value
            cls._injected_deco_params = injected_deco_params

            def __new__(cls, func=None, **kwargs):
                if cls._injected_deco_params and not set(kwargs).issubset(cls._injected_deco_params):
                    raise TypeError("TypeError: __new__() got unexpected keyword arguments: "
                                    f"{kwargs.keys() - cls._injected_deco_params}")
                if func is None:
                    return partial(cls, **kwargs)
                else:
                    return Decorator.__new__(cls, func, **kwargs)

            __new__.__signature__ = Signature(params)
            cls.__new__ = __new__
```

It passes the tests listed in the question, but I'm not super experienced with this kind of object oriented magic, so would be curious to see alternative solutions.

Comment: What are `Parameter`, `PK`, and `Signature`? Also, that `Parameter('self', PK)` looks pretty suspicious, given that you're attaching this signature to `__new__`. And why does `__new__` not complain about keyword arguments when the subclass declares no arguments?

Comment: And why are `Decora` and `Decorator` two separate classes?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica: Indeed, I forgot the imports and aliases. Sorry. Added. about the `Decorator` and `Decora` separation, it was more to keep a simple/light `Decorator` separate from the `Decora` attempt to create a more minimal interface to it.